# what serverless pattern is recommended when using many models?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, serverless

serverless's microservice pattern creates each CRUD as an individual function. If I have 40 tables, it means I will have 40 * 4 functions. 160 lambda is too much to maintain. I see there is services/monolithic pattern but can't find easily example. is there any reference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetutils,

I faced this while I was writing the restful server-less API. One suggestion is to use switch statement (or any middle-ware) to check the payload of the request and perform CRUD operations accordingly.

It'll surely decrease the number of lambda functions.

Thanks!

Comment: i see servrless pattern summarized in 3 types : microservices / services / monolithic . among 3, services seems to be a better fit in this case which is what you are proposing.